# show that the straight lines $(a^2-3b^2)x^2+8abxy+(b^2-3a^2)y^2=0$ form with the lie $ax+by+c=o$ an equilateral triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, area

show that the straight lines 
$(a^2-3b^2)x^2+8abxy+(b^2-3a^2)y^2=0$ form with the lie ax+by+c=o
an equilateral triangle whose area is $\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{3}(a^2+b^2)}$

is there any other way to solve without intersection points. Also the Angle between the first two lines is 60 degrees.any another way to solve this.

Comment: If I have real numbers $F,G,H,$ what can you tell me about the two lines $F x^2 + G xy+ H y^2 = 0?$

Comment: if the straight line is ax^2+2hxy+by^2.then angle between then is 2root(h^2-ab)/(a+b)

Comment: 2 straight lines passing through origin. we can find its angle bisector by (x^2-y^2)/a-b=xy/h

Comment: If I have a real number $m > 0,$ what is the angle between the half-line $y=mx$ with $x \geq 0$ and the positive part of the $x$-axis?

Comment: tan inverse m...

Comment: What are the $m$ values of the two lines in $F x^2 + G xy+ H y^2 = 0?$ What you do is divide all by $x^2.$

Comment: m1m2=f/g and m1+m2=-g/b

Comment: You need to find the two separate values. Meanwhile, it is $m = \frac{y}{x}$ after dividing through by $x^2.$

Comment: i have already tries with this..not able to solve it

Comment: ?????????????????????plz help...

Comment: Standard questions: where did you get this problem, and what is your background in mathematics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was saying, if we have three constants $F,G,H$ and $$ F x^2 + G x y + H y^2 = 0,  $$ we divide through by $x^2$ to arrive at $$ F  + G \frac{y}{x} + H \frac{y^2}{x^2} = 0.  $$ Or, as I said, using the traditional $m = \frac{y}{x},$ we get
$$ F + G m + H m^2 = 0,$$ or in order
$$ H m^2 + G m + F = 0.$$

We suspect we are describing two lines passing through the origin. If so, the slope(s) $m$ satisfy
$$ m = \frac{-G \pm \sqrt {G^2 - 4 HF}}{2H}.  $$
So, if $G^2 - 4 F H > 0,$ we do have two different slopes and two lines. For your original problem $$ F = a^2 - 3 b^2, G = 8 a b, H = b^2 - 3 a^2   $$

Comment: But how will you find the area from this ?

Comment: This will only give the equation of straight lines which we can find by using $$\alpha x + y(h \pm \sqrt{h^2 - \alpha\beta})=0$$ where $\alpha = F, \beta = H, h = G/2$.

Comment: How do I prove that the pair of lines are inclined at 60 degrees to each other?